# Grouping Multiple Raster Layers using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, arcgis-10.2, merge

How do I create multiple raster layers group, for example when using several aerial photos?

I wish to group the layers into one so that I can edit/select as a batch rather than having to click on individual layers.

I use ArcGIS Desktop 10.2.

Comment: Are you looking to mosaic the imagery?

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
This won't work for me, because i want to be able to work with the rasters separately.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'edit/select as a batch'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If Mosaic isn't what you need then take a look at

Working with group layers:
http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00s500000011000000

within Arc.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you can [create a raster catalog](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000008z000000) and then, for instance, loads all the raster datasets stored in the same workspace into it with the **[Workspace To Raster Catalog](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000093000000)** tool.

Alternatively:

> Use the **[Mosaic To New Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000098000000)** tool to merge multiple rasters into a new output raster.

Comment: Thank you for your reply!
I actually want to work with every layer separately.

Comment: What does mean _group in one layer_ and _work with every layer separately_? Maybe do you mean a raster catalog? If so, I've updated the answer. Otherwise, Rob's answer is what you need.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't looking to mosaic your rasters, it sounds like you just want to group them.

Have a look at creating a **[Group Layer](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s500000011000000)** on the ESRI help page.

If that doesn't help, perhaps have a look at the [**Overview of the Raster Toolset**](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/An_overview_of_the_Raster_toolset/001700000084000000/) on the ESRI help page.